# Python tkinter - problem with scrollbar after adding menu column

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on my application connected with my database.
I had a working wersion of it but it didn't look good so I want to add a left side menu to it.
That's how 'show records' page looked like:

photo 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0dBy.jpg

Code of this part:

```
def createTable(frame, row):
   columns = ('IMIĘ','NAZWISKO','PESEL','EMAIL','NR TELEFONU','NR POLISY','DOSTAWCA','WYGASA\nZA (DNI)','NOTATKA','WYŚLIJ\nSMS','WYŚLIJ\nEMAIL')
   column_counter = 0
   for column in columns:
       column_label = Label(frame, text=column, bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, font="Helvetica 10")
       column_label.grid(row=row,column=column_counter,padx=2)
       column_counter += 1


def addRecord(frame, row, record):
    column = 0
    for i in range(13): #12 columns in database
        if i in (6,7): #records from data base that I don't use
            continue
        elif i == 11 and notify==True:
            send_sms = Button(frame, text="SMS", bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, font="Helvetica 10", command=partial(sendSMSNotification, [], record[5])) #button that sends sms
            send_sms.grid(row=row,column=9,padx=2) 
        elif i == 12 and notify==True:
            send_email = Button(frame, text="EMAIL", bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, font="Helvetica 10", command=partial(sendEmailNotification, [], record[5])) #button that sends EMAIL
            send_email.grid(row=row,column=10,padx=2)
        else:
            result_label = Label(frame, text=record[i], bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, font="Helvetica 10")
            result_label.grid(row=row,column=column,padx=2)
            column += 1

def showRecords(): 
 destroyWidgets() #clears window
 main_frame = Frame(root, bg=BG_COLOR)
 main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
 my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame, bg=BG_COLOR)
 my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
 my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
 my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
 my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
 my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: 
 my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))
 second_frame = Frame(my_canvas, bg=BG_COLOR)
 my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

 conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
 c = conn.cursor()

 back_button_top = Button(second_frame, text='Powrót', width=135, command=lambda: returnMain())
 back_button_top.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, padx=20)


 result_frame = Frame(second_frame, bg=BG_COLOR)
 result_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
 createTable(result_frame, 0) #creates a heading of the table ('IMIĘ, NAZWISKO, PESEL' etc)
 c.execute("SELECT * FROM dane")
 records = c.fetchall()
 row_counter = 2
 for record in records:
    addRecord(result_frame, row_counter, record) #adds a line of data read from the database, looked like a excel 
    row_counter+=1
```

Then I added a simple left sided menu column. So I added these lines to the showrecords function.
showMenu creates a Frame in column 0 and adds some buttons

```
def showMenu():
  menu_frame = Frame(root,bg=BG_COLOR)
  menu_frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='ew')
  menu_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
  show_records_button = Button(....

def showRecords(): 
  destroyWidgets()
  showMenu()
  record_frame = Frame(root, bg=BG_COLOR)
  record_frame.grid(column=1, row=0,sticky='nsew')
  main_frame = Frame(record_frame, bg=BG_COLOR)
  main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
  ......
```

photo 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZMkv.jpg

And now I'm getting the scrollbar in the center of records column. Do you know how can I move the scroll to the right side of window? I think I have tried to change every possible attribute and nothing helped.
Also the problem of small Frame appears if I add an addition (just like my new version of code but without line with showMenu() Frame without adding a menu. So probably something is wrong with the sizing, but I dont know what.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that doesn't require an external database. You should be able to either use some static data, or generate the data when the UI starts.

Comment: if you add the scrollbar to the root window, you can simply put it either on `side='right'` or if using `.grid` on the last column